# Exporting a matrix in R to an excel workbook

Tags: excel, r

I have several matrices in R and would like to export them as separate sheets to an existing workbook. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: There's a whole topic in reading/writing from R in the manuals: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html) library:

```
d <- matrix( rnorm(1000), ncol = 10 )

require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook( "wb.xlsx", create=FALSE )
createSheet(wb, name="sheet1")
writeWorksheet( wb, as.data.frame(d), sheet="sheet1" )
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook( "wb.xls", create=TRUE )
createSheet(wb, name="sheet1")
writeWorksheet( wb,as.data.frame(A), sheet="sheet1" )
Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (0) is out of range (0..-1)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```